# sqlite setup for immediate writes but can't corrupt old data

Tags: sqlite

I am trying to figure out how to best configure sqlite3. I need writes to be very fast but I can't risk the entire database getting corrupt in the event of a power failure. I don't care if the last write or last few writes are lost in the event of a power failure. I just don't want all the data to be lost. What would be the best settings to use to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

What you are looking for is the Write ahead log, or [WAL journalling mode](http://www.sqlite.org/wal.html).  Otherwise, there is also the asynchronous I/O module.  You will find information about it here: [An Asynchronous I/O Module For SQLite](http://www.sqlite.org/asyncvfs.html).

It saves writes to a queue which is dispatched to the filesystem in a background thread.  The transactional guarantees still apply so as long as your transactions are composed correctly, there's no danger of corrupting the database.